# Xml serialization. Deserialize and convert to a different object

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I have class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlElement("Date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

It was XML serialized to a file:

```
var myClass = new MyClass() { Date = new DateTime(2010, 09, 24) };
new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass)).Serialize(fileStream, myClass);
```

The result:

```
<MyClass>
    <Date>2010-09-24T00:00:00</Date>
</MyClass>
```

After that the new date-holder class was created:

```
public class MyDate
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Date { get; set; }
}
```

And was used in MyClass instead of System.DateTime:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlElement("Date")]
    public MyDate Date { get; set; }
}
```

What I need is to make following code work fine:

```
MyClass myClass = (MyClass)new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass)).Deserialize(fileStream);
```

The problem is I can't change the MyClass. The only things I can change are MyDate class and serialization/deserialization code.

**How to make the deserialization code so as new class MyDate is deserialized from previously serialized System.DateTime?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to implement [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) on the `MyDate` class and then parse the date string in the `ReadXml` method using [`XmlConvert.ToDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162342.aspx).

If the purpose of the `MyDate` class is to have a different XML format, then you could support both input formats in the `ReadXml` method by checking what is actually present in the element, but always write to the new format in the `WriteXml` method.

Comment: IXmlSerializable.ReadXml is never invoked. I dunno why. Any ideas?

Comment: If you've implemented it on the `MyDate` type it should always be invoked by the serializer... No idea why it wouldn't be I'm afraid, it has always worked in the past when I've used it.